# Getting invalid date if year is greater than 4 characters without moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to convert my UTC time into a local time. The code works fine as long as the year is 4 characters; however, if it is greater, it is throwing:

**RangeError: Invalid time value at date.toISOString ()**

I tried different things and found out that my date object is throwing this exception because it contains "Invalid Date" when it's trying to transform a date like *"22222-01-23T12:30:26.000Z"* into ISOString.

```html
<Form.Group as={Col}>
    <Form.Label>Future Date</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control id="futureDate" type="datetime-local" name="futureDate" placeholder="Future Date" value={UtcToDiffTime(futureDate) || ""} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
</Form.Group>
```

```js
static UtcToDiffTime(utc){
        let date = new Date(utc);
        date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
        return date.toISOString().slice(0, date.toISOString().lastIndexOf(":")));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can convert my date regardless of the year's characters or make date contain a valid date string?

I am trying to truncate *"22222-01-23T12:30:26.000Z"* into *"22222-01-23T12:30"* without using moment.js.

Comment: "22222-01-23T12:30:26.000Z" is already an ISOString, UTC's are formatted like "Sun, 31 Dec 1899 00:00:00 GMT," so make sure you're passing a proper UTC string to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for formatting like this.

Also, the iso string format [mandates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) 4 digits for the year. Any deviation is 'upon mutual agreement' meaning: not standardized.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add without momentjs. I have edited my question.

Then is it possible to limit my form input to enter the years up to 4 characters or less?